# Distributed parallel programming model in any programming language - similar to apach hadoop but supports windows machine

Tags: php, python, perl, parallel-processing, distributed

I am interested in understanding a distributed parallel programming model in any programming language (Java/Perl/Python/PHP) - similar to Apache Hadoop but which supports Windows machines (I don't want to install Cygwin).

Also, i am not keen on high availability and fault tolerance.

Example:
Create a job "sum" and submit it from client so that it runs in many worker nodes (including windows machine without cygwin)

```
sum(int a, int b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please consider Gearman: http://gearman.org/

The perl gearman server is running under windows, without cygwin: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Gearman/

http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

Comment: I assume, in gearman the job/task is defined in the worker code and registered with the server and the client will invoke or request for the job. But i am asking for a client where job will be configured instead of the worker node (similar to hadoop). Also, it should run on windows machine without cygwin.

Comment: Please see my notes: The Perl based gearman server does not need cygwin, as far as I know (i am not talking about the original gearman here)

Comment: @user703555: You are correct, but this is Perl :-). I think you could write a worker that receives a code as string, the data and eval the code using the data. It is a bit odd but it could work if you did not have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is  [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) ... You can simply implement multiple workers on windows without cygwin

Here is a simple Parallel task worker in PHP where It receives a message, sleeps for that number of seconds, then signals that it's finished

```
$context = new ZMQContext();

// Socket to receive messages on
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->connect("tcp://localhost:5557");

// Socket to send messages to
$sender = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$sender->connect("tcp://localhost:5558");

// Process tasks forever
while ( true ) {
    $string = $receiver->recv();
    $json = json_decode($string,true);

    // Do the work
    echo sum($json['left'], $json['right']), PHP_EOL;  // <--- call SUM
    usleep(strlen($string) * 1000);

    // Send results to sink
    $sender->send("");
}
```

[Here is a good place to start](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3aall)

Answer (score 0):

try [IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html) for parallel computing!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org) or [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com), both are Java distributed frameworks that will work on any platform